# How do I combine consecutive messages sent in a short time frame together and only return the most recent post request?

Tags: twilio

I'm making a conversation bot.

Let's say that we have 2 consecutive messages sent 3 seconds of each other

HTTP POST "Hi"

HTTP POST "Whats up"

I don't want to respond twice to twilios webhook

**How do I combine them requests into**

HTTP POST "HI" <-- return nothing

HTTP POST "Hi whats up" return response

I figured a way to get the combined request but I don't know how to disregard the first post request if there ends up being a another consecutive message in a short time frame.